# Select random list item and add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

At the moment I have an unordered list with the id of menu and one list item within this ul has a class of "selected" 
what i would like to do is grab all the list items from within the ul and remove the inital selected class from the list item it is on then assign it to a different list item within the same ul each time the page is refreshed.

Is this possible? Whats the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Yes , that is possible .. But you need to store that info in a cookie and use that information as the data does not persist after a page is refreshed..

Comment: any help on how i go about that...?

Comment: what have you done so far john? you have had enough pointers from Susanth...

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $ulLen = $('#menu li').length;

    $('#menu li').removeClass('selected'); // Remove the class

    // Select random li..

    var rand = Math.floor( (Math.random()* $ulLen ) );  // Select  a random li..

     $('#menu li:eq('+ rand + ')').addClass('selected'); 

     // Add the selected class to randomly selected li...

});
```

**[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/QYC8w/1/)**

Comment: why dont you check if the value matches the cookie value and re-run this function? :)

Comment: yup.. that can be done as well .. But I wanted to keep it simple.. so avoided cookies in this case

Comment: Why not use sessionStorage instead of cookies? That would be simple enough

Comment: this seems to be what i am looking for but sometimes when running it no li's have the class "selected" ?

Comment: I don't think that should be happening ?? Seems to be working in the fiddle.. Can you reproduce that issue ??

Comment: The code in the fiddle is wrong, it has `+1` at the end of the `rand` assignment which causes 1-8 vs 0-7 mismatching (first element never selected, and rand=8 -> no element selected). The code in the answer itself does not have the `+1`

Comment: I fixed that in the code but missed that in the fiddle.. I have updated that

Comment: I did a quick mod showing using window.sessionStorage to remember the last one. https://gist.github.com/3934580

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be written shorter, but I wanted it more verbose so you could see the steps. Technically this could pick the same one twice. If you wanted, you could use LocalStorage or a cookie to remember the last item and not select it again. I went for simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>


    $(document).ready(function() {

        //remove the selected class from the li that has it
        $("li.selected").removeClass("selected");

        //get all the LIs
        var menuItems = $("ul#menu li");
        //How many do we have?
        var numItems = menuItems.length;
        console.log(numItems);
        //Pick one by randm
        var selected = Math.floor(Math.random()*numItems);
        console.log(selected);
        //And set it
        $("ul#menu li:nth-child("+(selected+1)+")").addClass("selected");
    });
    </script>

    <style>
        li.selected { background-color: red; }
    </style>
</head> 

<body> 

<ul id="menu">
    <li>Item one</li>
    <li>Item two</li>
    <li>Item three</li>
    <li class="selected">Item four</li>
    <li>Item five</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/eWbqa/8/

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var tags = menu.getElementsByTagName('li');

tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)].setAttribute('class', 'selected');
```

You could expand on that, but that will do it.

*Edited to reflect Naveen's good advice.

Comment: `tags[Math.floor(Math.random() * tags.length)]` please... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random